# onkeyup and onkeydown not catching anything

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Can someone tell me whats going on? My console isn't throwing any exceptions.

```
    function onKeyDown(){
                    var e = event.keyCode;

                    //if (e==87 /*w*/){
                        up = true;
                        throw('up'); 
                    //}

                    if (e==65 /*a*/){
                        left = true;
                    }

                    if (e==83 /*s*/){
                        down = true;
                    }

                    if (e==68 /*d*/){
                        right = true;
                    }
                }

                function onKeyUp(){
                    var e = event.keyCode;

                    //if (e==87 /*w*/){
                        up = false;
                        throw('up'); 
                    //}

                    if (e==65 /*a*/){
                        left = false;
                    }

                    if (e==83 /*s*/){
                        down = false;
                    }

                    if (e==68 /*d*/){
                        right = false;
                    }
                }

Okay, so that was the javascript, and this is the html:

    <body>
            <input id="ss" type="button" value="start/stop" />
            <div id="container" style="border:1px solid; cursor:none; width:480px; height:320px;">
                <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"  onkeyup="onKeyUp();" onkeydown="onKeydown();">
                    Canvas not displaying.
                </canvas>
            </div>
        </body>



Edit: current code:
```

window.onload = function(){
                init();
            };

```
function init(){
                initSettings();
                initImages();

                document.getElementById('canvas').onkeydown = function(event) {
                    var e = event.keyCode;

                    //if (e==87 /*w*/){
                        up = true;
                        throw('up'); 
                    //}

                    if (e==65 /*a*/){
                        left = true;
                    }

                    if (e==83 /*s*/){
                        down = true;
                    }

                    if (e==68 /*d*/){
                        right = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I dont know the reason behind, but in ALL the codes I have seen having canvas that deals with key events, **I have seen that the events are registered with the windows, NOT with the canvas**. Here is an example:  http://html5.litten.com/make-a-maze-game-on-an-html5-canvas/#thecode

Comment: Is that using JQuery, cause I'm not using that.

Comment: no, it's not... did you look at the code?  It's presented right there on the same page.  Sarwar's point is that it is an example of a page using canvas but it attaches its keyboard event handler to the `window` object (though in a way that won't work in IE either I might add), not the canvas, which might be your problem (see also thirtydot's comment below).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be doing something like this:

```
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    ...
}
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    ...
}
```

And get rid of:

```
onkeyup="onKeyUp();" onkeydown="onKeydown();"
```

---

The quick test page I made which works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
 event = event || window.event;

 var e = event.keyCode;

 //if (e==87 /*w*/){
  up = true;
  throw('up'); 
 //}

 if (e==65 /*a*/){
  left = true;
 }

 if (e==83 /*s*/){
  down = true;
 }

 if (e==68 /*d*/){
  right = true;
 }
}

document.onkeyup=function(event) {
 event = event || window.event;

 var e = event.keyCode;

 //if (e==87 /*w*/){
  up = false;
  throw('up'); 
 //}

 if (e==65 /*a*/){
  left = false;
 }

 if (e==83 /*s*/){
  down = false;
 }

 if (e==68 /*d*/){
  right = false;
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="ss" type="button" value="start/stop" />
    <div id="container" style="border:1px solid; cursor:none; width:480px; height:320px;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320">
            Canvas not displaying.
        </canvas>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: or in his case `document.getElementById("canvas").onkeydown = ...`, etc., I presume?  Also, don't forget to do `event = event || window.event;` first thing in each of those handlers (so that IE doesn't crap out.  Incidentally, I'm pretty sure his original code will crap out in everything else.)

Comment: Maybe I was just *doing it wrong*, but I couldn't get the events to fire if I attached them to the canvas element.

Comment: Ah. That might be part of his problem as well then :)  Admittedly I haven't used canvas yet.

Comment: Did you also try @Ken Franqueiro's tip about `window.event` and IE? What browser are you testing with?

Comment: I'm using firefox right now, and yeah, I did but I think it's JQuery

Comment: I edited my answer with my working test page. You should have said (or tagged) that you have jQuery available - it makes it so much easier.

Comment: If I read his comment above correctly, he's *not* using jQuery, he's just mistaking half the code we suggest to him as being jQuery when it's also *not* jQuery...

Comment: No, no. I DON'T use JQuery. This worked though, so I've accepted it. thank you very much!

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro: Oh, I see. Thanks for your help with this question.